# Microsoft Graph API - Accessing files for Group

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am building an application which needs to use the Microsoft Graph API to access a particular file which exists within the documents  for a particular Group within my organisation.

I have identified the Group ID for the group in which the document lives, however I cannot figure out how to access the drive for this particular group.

If I do a GET request for "/groups/{ID}/drive" or for "/groups/{ID}/drive/root/children/" I get the following response:

```
{   'error': {   'code': 'ResourceNotFound',
                 'innerError': {   'date': '2020-05-20T14:50:24',
                                   'request-id': '155cdb67-49b4-4f87-9b04-ce68e9f34364'},
                 'message': 'Unable to provision resource.'}}
```

I have previously managed to work with files within my OneDrive or a particular SP site using the Microsoft Graph API, however I cannot identify the group documents.

The API reference docs for the Group resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0) do not seem to contain information about a method for accessing the documents, despite the overview page for the Graph API indicating that it does contain a "get files" method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Does such a method exist? Or is there a different way of accessing the Group's files - e.g through a particular SP site?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below endpoints

> GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children
>   [List Children of a
>   drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Also you can use below for searching

> GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}
>   [Search for an
>   item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting an error when I try to use any methods that access the drive for the group.

```
{'error': {'code': 'ResourceNotFound',
           'innerError': {'date': '2020-05-22T09:28:03',
                          'request-id': 'df9e03a4-ee2b-4fb7-a3fe-8d6cc6446d48'},
           'message': 'Unable to provision resource.'}}
```

It is strange because it seems to be saying that the drive is not provisioned for the group but I can clearly see documents associated with the group on Teams and Sharepoint.